# TinyMCE Links incorrect on save

Tags: tinymce, plone

I have a Plone 4.3.3 site.  My logged in URL is different than the non-logged in URL.  For example, the anonymous URL would be http://mysite.somewhere.com.  When logged in, the URL is https://loggedin.mysite.somewhere.com.

When I create a link on a page and click save, if I view the page anonymously, the link is incorrect, displaying as the https version.  However, if I go back and just open the page and click save, the link will be fixed and when view anonymously, it is fine.

These are internal links within the site and the site is not set to use UID's.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Link you are talking of are internal link to site contents? Also: are you using the "Link using UID" feature?

Comment: These are internal links and we're not using UID's at the moment.

Comment: Why is the logged in URL a subdomain "loggedin"? That's not out of the box setup is it?

Comment: You should use the "Link using UID" feature. Bud I guess in your case also something else is wrong with your environment beside Plone (Apache?, nginx?). Usually the `virtual host monster` handles the urls correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a bug report for this issue and it should have been fixed recently according to the comments there
https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13721

afaics 1.3.7 already contains this changes, so try to pin that version in your buildout
https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/commits/1.3.x

Comment: Thank you.  I'll pin it up and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: For anyone that may have had this issue, the solution that fRiSi suggested does in fact correct the problem.  Thank you folks.